# two functions with onchange

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I am using the following code in my .jsp:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function radioClick(e) {
    // workaround for IE, which fires the changed event merely when the focus changes
    e.blur();
    e.focus();
}

function showFoo(e) {
    document.getElementById('foo_agb').style.visibility = 
        e.checked && e.id == 'foo_radio_button' ? 'visible' : 'hidden';
    document.getElementById('foo_birthday').style.visibility = 
        e.checked && e.id == 'foo_radio_button' ? 'visible' : 'hidden';
}

function hideFoo(e) {
    document.getElementById('foo_agb').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    document.getElementById('foo_birthday').style.visibility = 'hidden';
}



function showBar(e) {
    document.getElementById('bar_agb').style.visibility = 
        w.checked && e.id == 'bar_radio_button' ? 'visible' : 'hidden';
    document.getElementById('bar_personalnr').style.visibility = 
        w.checked && e.id == 'bar_radio_button' ? 'visible' : 'hidden';
}

function hideBar(e) {
    document.getElementById('bar_agb').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    document.getElementById('bar_personalnr').style.visibility = 'hidden';
}
</script>
```

This needs to be called by clicking a radio button like that:

```
<%
        if (unrelatedstuff){
            }

%>
<INPUT id="foo_radio_button" <%=checked%> type="Radio" value="unrelated" name="Something" onclick="radioClick(this)" onchange="showFoo(this); hideBar(this);"> <%=list[i].getName()%><br>
<%
        }

        else if (moreunrelatedstuff){
                }

%>
<INPUT id="bar_radio_button" <%=checked%> type="Radio" value="unrelated" name="Something" onclick="radioClick(this)" onchange="showBar(this); hideFoo(this);"> <%=list[i].getName()%><br>
<%
        }
        else {
            if (youguessditevenmoreunrelatedstuff){
            }
%>
<INPUT <%=checked%> type="Radio" value="unrelated" name="Something" onclick="radioClick(this)" onchange="hideFoo(this); hideBar(this);"> <%=list[i].getName()%><br>
```

I thought i can call more than one function with "onchange", like "showFoo; hideBar;" but it doesn't seem to work.

Any ideas what i could have done wrong, or how to achieve more than one action per "onChange"?

Comment: Call the other function inside one function, and if it's only supposed to be called sometimes then use an if statement to check a condition. There's probably an easier way, but that's what I'd do

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you avoid obstrusive javascript and move everything into an external file.

```
var currentObject = document.getElementById("bar_radio_button");
currentObject.addEventListener("change", function() {
    other_function();
    another_function();
});
```

Comment: What's the point in teaching students to do it the other way if this is more efficient/organized? Sincerely, someone slightly mad I went through an entire semester of the other way

Comment: I think it's easier to understand. You see an html element and you literally attach events to it. If you write unobstrusive javascript you first need to get a reference to the DOM element and some people might get confused by this, especially it they're not yet 100% familiar with classes, ids and tags. Obstrusive JS is a fast start, unobstrusive is more oranised and avoids confusion in bigger projects.

Comment: @pbrianq `concept > efficiently`. Sometimes concepts are more important on doing something a certain way. It's why bubble-sort is taught before quick-sort. Sometimes a better way involves too much overhead for the class, and a simpler ("worst") way is used to help student understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, already found my error right after posting it.. I had

```
w.checked
```

instead of

```
e.checked
```

in one of the functions.

Sometimes, you can't see the forest because of all the trees.. :)